# Unable to insert a record in MySQL table from HTML5 and PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html

I'm unable to insert a record here. Not sure why. My login works. My two `echo` statements work. But no record gets recorded. All the variables that begin with 'type' or 'subj' are checkbox form elements, so I set those columns to 'Null' in the db (using phpMyAdmin). Not sure if that's correct - the idea is they're not required. Also, the first column in my db is not an entry from this form, it's supposed to be an id for the entry, set as primary key, not-null, and set to auto-increment. This is my first time doing this. How can I test what's happening? Thank you! - *and what the heck happened to my codeblock!!!*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Submit entry to database </title>
    </head>
    <body>  <?php
    //when Submit clicked
    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    $data_source = 'mysql:host=myHost;dbname=myDatabase';
    $db_user = 'myUserName';
    $db_password = 'myPassword';
    $db = new PDO($data_source, $db_user, $db_password);

    //load the form data into variables
    $reviewer = $_POST['reviewer'];
    $osj = $_POST['osj'];
    $touchDate = $_POST['touchDate'];
    $typeAction = $_POST['typeAction'];
    $typeTech = $_POST['typeTech'];
    $typeReg = $_POST['typeReg'];
    $subjSuit = $_POST['subjSuit'];
    $subjMFtran = $_POST['subjMFtran'];
    $subjConcen = $_POST['subjConcen'];
    $subjOption = $_POST['subjOption'];
    $subjTrade = $_POST['subjTrade'];
    $subjMuni = $_POST['subjMuni'];
    $subjUIT = $_POST['subjUIT'];
    $subjBkRecMFdir = $_POST['subjBkRecMFdir'];
    $subjOBA = $_POST['subjOBA'];
    $subjOther = $_POST['subjOther'];
    $flavor = $_POST['flavor'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    echo $reviewer;
    //prepare SQL statement
    $statement = "INSERT INTO tblBranchTouches 
    (reviewer, osj, touchDate, typeAction, typeTech, typeReg, subjSuit, 
    subjMFtran, subjConcen, subjOption, subjTrade, subjMuni, subjUIT, subjBkRecMFdir, 
    subjOBA, subjOther, flavor, notes) 
    VALUES ('$reviewer', '$osj', '$touchDate', '$typeAction', '$typeTech', '$typeReg', '$subjSuit', 
    '$subjMFtran', '$subjConcen', '$subjOption', '$subjTrade', '$subjMuni', '$subjUIT', '$subjBkRecMFdir', 
    '$subjOBA', '$subjOther', '$flavor', '$notes') ";
    $db->query($statement);
    //confirm
    echo "<h1>Thank You</h1>";
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
    <label>
      Reviewer: 
      <input type="text" name="reviewer" list="ARTies">
      <datalist id="ARTies">
        <option value = "MWeber">
        <option value = "JBurchill">
        <option value = "DGlazer">
        <option value = "EKiburz">
        <option value = "CSupak">
        <option value = "MVallery">
        <option value = "CHo">
        <option value = "HPatil">
        <option value = "NVanDoorn">
      </datalist>
    </label>
    <label>
      OSJ: 
      <input type="text" name="osj" maxlength=3 size=3>
    </label>
    <input type="date" name="touchDate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y/m/d'))); ?>">
    </p>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Type: </legend>
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="typeAction"> Action </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="typeTech"> Tech. </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="typeReg"> Reg.</label></p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Subject: </legend>
    <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjSuit"> Suitability </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjMFtrans"> MF Transactions </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjConcen"> Concentrations </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjOption"> Options </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjTrade"> Trade Review </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjMuni"> Munis </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjUIT"> UITs </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjBkRecMFdir"> Bks-Recs-MFDirect </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjOBA"> OBAs  </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="subjOther"> Other </label>
    </p>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
    <label>
      Flavor: 
      <input type="number" name="flavor" min=1 max=5 value=3>
    </label>
    <label>Notes: <textarea name="notes"></textarea></label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ENTER">
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What you are doing is extremely dangerous.  You are wide open to SQL injection and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: have you checked by die(mysql_error()) show the result you are getting form this

Comment: I'm very new to this, apologies. Where and how would you implement the die() statement?

Comment: Also, I thought I was using PDO... Brad, could you elaborate?

Comment: I researched more on PDO, and I have a solution that I understand is safe. Also, the PDO statement I have helps identify errors...  $conn = new PDO($data_source, $db_user, $db_password, 
                    array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what is now working for me. I just wish I didn't have to write my form variables about 7 different times. Thanks again...

```
<?php
//when Submit clicked
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
  $data_source = 'mysql:host=myHost;dbname=myDB';
  $db_user = 'myUsername';
  $db_password = 'myPass';
  //create a new PDO object - constructor takes at most 4 parameters, DSN, username, password, 
  //and an array of driver options
  //a DSN is basically a string of options that tell PDO which driver to use, and the connection details
  $conn = new PDO($data_source, $db_user, $db_password, 
                array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
  //first driver option turns off prepare emulation which is enabled in MySQL driver by default, but really should be turned off to use PDO safely
  //second driver option puts PDO into exception mode
  //
  //load the form data into variables
  $reviewer = $_POST['reviewer'];
  //(more)      
  //prepare SQL statement
  $sql="INSERT INTO tblBranchTouches 
    (reviewer, osj, touchDate, typeAction, typeTech, typeReg, subjSuit, 
    subjMFtrans, subjConcen, subjOption, subjTrade, subjMuni, subjUIT, subjBkRecMFdir, 
    subjOBA, subjOther, flavor, notes) 
    VALUES (:reviewer, :osj, :touchDate, :typeAction, :typeTech, :typeReg, :subjSuit, 
    :subjMFtrans, :subjConcen, :subjOption, :subjTrade, :subjMuni, :subjUIT, :subjBkRecMFdir, 
    :subjOBA, :subjOther, :flavor, :notes)";
  $q = $conn->prepare($sql);  
  $q->execute(array(':reviewer'=>$reviewer, ':osj'=>$osj, ':touchDate'=>$touchDate, ':typeAction'=>$typeAction, ':typeTech'=>$typeTech, 
                   ':typeReg'=>$typeReg, ':subjSuit'=>$subjSuit, ':subjMFtrans'=>$subjMFtrans, ':subjConcen'=>$subjConcen, ':subjOption'=>$subjOption, 
                   ':subjTrade'=>$subjTrade, ':subjMuni'=>$subjMuni, ':subjUIT'=>$subjUIT, ':subjBkRecMFdir'=>$subjBkRecMFdir, ':subjOBA'=>$subjOBA, 
                   ':subjOther'=>$subjOther, ':flavor'=>$flavor, ':notes'=>$notes));
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

for `INSERT`, you need to use `pdo::exec`, this will return the no. of rows inserted. http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php `pdo::query` is used for `SELECT` queries.

so your statement would be,

```
   $statement = "INSERT INTO tblBranchTouches 
(reviewer, osj, touchDate, typeAction, typeTech, typeReg, subjSuit, 
subjMFtran, subjConcen, subjOption, subjTrade, subjMuni, subjUIT, subjBkRecMFdir, 
subjOBA, subjOther, flavor, notes) 
VALUES ('$reviewer', '$osj', '$touchDate', '$typeAction', '$typeTech', '$typeReg', '$subjSuit', 
'$subjMFtran', '$subjConcen', '$subjOption', '$subjTrade', '$subjMuni', '$subjUIT', '$subjBkRecMFdir', 
'$subjOBA', '$subjOther', '$flavor', '$notes') ";
$count = $db->exec($statement);
if($count > 0)
  echo "<h1>Thank You</h1>";
else //else statement if you need it
  echo "<h1>No records were inserted.</h1>";
```

Comment: I'm getting the 'no records were inserted'.

Comment: There were none, until I modified the PDO to include errors, which helped a lot...   $conn = new PDO($data_source, $db_user, $db_password, 
                    array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

Answer (score 0):

You can check the error with the following:

if ($db->error)
    echo $db->error;

Very useful! Never assume that a query was successful; you always want to check for errors.

Comment: I placed that statement a few places, but it gives no feedback. Maybe there's not an error, but still not doing the insert I need?

Comment: Place it right after the insert. If you call an insert command and it doesn't insert any rows into the database, it should give you an error. $db->query("INSERT INTO..."); if ($db->error) echo $db->error; else echo "success!";